# ImageButton setEnabled in Adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to set one button to enabled and a different one to disabled once it is clicked on the listView. There are 2 buttons and I am trying to change them in the onClick in the getView function of my adapter.

Here is the onCLick of one of them.

```
    holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Event", "Up");
            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
            ImageButton uButton = (ImageButton) parentRow.findViewById(R.id.upImageView);
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
            if (activity.equals("Host"))
            {
            } else {

            }

            uButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

thank you

Comment: You code looks incomplete. position is not being used. And I only see one button being referenced.  You said you had two buttons?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to change the view inside an `onClick()` function, it will not work.

You didn't post a lot of code, so I will just describe the correct code.

First, your adapter needs to model the enabled state of the two buttons.  In other words, for each list item you need two booleans, one for each button.

In your view binding method, you need to access the two booleans and set the enabled state of each button based on its model boolean value.

In your `onClick()`, you need to flip the state of the two booleans and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list with the new button states.